# How to: Make a button shake every X seconds?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a button shake every couple of seconds when a certain bool is true ..

I've found a "ShakeWidget" that I've wrapped my button in, but struggling to figure out how to make it shake every couple of seconds...

Here's a little example of the code:

**This is the widget I'm wrapping my button with**

```dart
class ShakeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration duration;
  final double deltaX;
  final Widget child;
  final Curve curve;

  const ShakeWidget({
    Key key,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    this.deltaX = 20,
    this.curve = Curves.bounceOut,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// convert 0-1 to 0-1-0
  double shake(double animation) =>
      2 * (0.5 - (0.5 - curve.transform(animation)).abs());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      key: key,
      tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
      duration: duration,
      builder: (context, animation, child) => Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(deltaX * shake(animation), 0),
        child: child,
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

**Here's an example of what I've tried**

It's definitely not shaking every 2 seconds like I thought it would.. I've got a second bool/condition that's there to allow the button to start shaking if it's **true**

```
  bool _shakeButton = false;
  bool _canStartShaking = false;

  void _startShakeTimer() {
    _shakeTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
     if(_canStartShaking) 
      setState(() {
        _shakeButton = !_shakeButton;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startShakeTimer();
  }


  Widget _myShakingButton() {
    return _shakeButton
        ? ShakeWidget(
            child: CustomButton(
              buttonType: ButtonType.Primary,
              onPressedHandler: (){},
            ),
          )
        : CustomButton(
            buttonType: ButtonType.Primary,
            onPressedHandler: (){},
          );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `_canStartShaking` is set to `false`, so there is no way for `_shakeButton` to be set to `true` since that code only runs when `_canStartShaking` is `true`.

So the solution is to set `_canStartShaking` to `true` instead of `false`

```dart
bool _canStartShaking = true;
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I should have explained .. that bool changes based on something else (I didn't think that part was relevant but wanted to show that I don't want it to shake all of the time) .. Once it's set to true the button DOES shake... just not as frequently as I'm expecting.. i.e. if I set the timer duration to 1 second, I imagined it would switch between true and false every 2 seconds.. but it doesn't

Comment: How does it take to switch when you set it to 1 second?

Comment: Almost 5 seconds or more... It's weird. I've tried with "500 milliseconds" and it still seems to take about 5-10 seconds

Comment: I have no idea what's going on but it seems to be working like I expected now

Comment: Oh that's good. I also found this : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html says "The exact timing depends on the underlying timer implementation... the time between two consecutive callbacks can be shorter and longer than duration." So it might not be accurate all the time, maybe?